# Dask bag gets stuck on processing when blocksize is defined, only uses one worker when it's not defined

Tags: python, jupyter, etl, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to process a single large (1TB) json file locally with Dask. The file has one object per line. When I don't specify blocksize in the `read_text` function, the code runs perfectly but only on one worker. Only one partition is then made, and only one task can be seen in the dashboard. If I do specify `blocksize`, all workers get tasks, but they never move on from processing (at least not within 12 hours). What is going wrong? How do I get all workers to actually do work?

The code is as follows:

```py
import dask.bag as db
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=4, 
                threads_per_worker=2,
                memory_limit='2GB')

client = Client(cluster)

db.read_text('./data/uncompressed/latest-all.json', blocksize=1e8)\
    .map(lambda obj: obj[:-2])\
    .map(parse_json)\
    .map(prune)\
    .filter(lambda obj: obj != None)\
    .map(json.dumps)\
    .to_textfiles('./data/proc/*.json')
```

The `parse_json` and `prune` are both pure python functions with no IO.

Here's a snip of the dashboard when blocksize is defined:
[image: dask dashboard]

Comment: Could you please produce a little code to generate the data file showing this problem, so that we can recreate the issue.

Comment: @mdurant I've uploaded a sample json here of about 100 entities: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/40b5c4332d600805f33a3c7db28d512120200331160632/eed271

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that they are working, but that your functions are just very slow.  You can see what your workers are doing either by ...

1. Looking at the profile page to see what workers are spending time on
2. Looking at the info page, navigating to any worker, and then clicking on the "Call Stacks" button to see what they're working on

You might also consider smaller chunk sizes to see if that helps get things moving more quickly.

Comment: Hi @Mrocklin,thank you for your reply. If that were the case, I would expect at least an output file to have been created over the course of 10 hours? With a single worker several hundreds/thousands of entities are processed per minute, so I don't understand why four workers would be so much slower. They report that they are working on processing, which they never move on from.

Comment: Neither do I.  I don't know exactly what is going on in your situation.  The suggestions above are what I would recommend to try to investigate further.

Comment: Time seems to be split evenly between a listcomp and _next_. I can't do without the listcomp unfortunately, but with one worker i got about 2188 entities processed per second which is fast enough. However, the call stacks of all workers except one remain empty.

Increasing block size just makes that one worker load more stuff into memory.
Decreasing block size to 1Mb seems to have improved performance greatly over large or no blocks, but still only one worker reports to be working.